# List of characters in VBScript that require escape characters

Tags: vbscript, special-characters

I just learned that $ requires an escape character.  What other special characters are there in VBScript?

Also is there a boolean function where I can find out if a character is a special character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh? `WScript.Echo "$"` outputs $ without any escaping. The only special character in a VBScript string literal is the double quote (use [two in a row](http://jansfreeware.com/articles/asp-string-literals.html) for a literal double quote within a string).

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape bigmoney when using it in VBScript regular expressions, but that is a very specific case. You cannot use it as you are used to in some BASIC flavours, VBA or VB to assign the String primitive to a variable.
(like

```
10 FOR I = 1024 TO 1063
20 A$ = A$ + CHR$(PEEK(I))
30 NEXT I
40 ? A$;
50 A$ = ""
60 GOTO 10
```

for the C64 or

```
Dim i, original$, final$
original$ = "Hello World!"
' Premature optimization rules! xxx$ functions are faster than xxx functions!
final$ = Left$(original$, 3) & Chr$(112) & Chr$(32) & Chr$(109) & Mid$(original$, 2, 1) & Right$(original$, 7)
MsgBox final$
```

In good ol' VB6)

Just eliminate the $ in the latter example, you don't need them.

If you really, really, really want to use the $ in routine or variable naming, you can always use the brackets like:

```
Sub [Wow! does thi$ really works? I'm a 1337 h4x0rz!]
    MsgBox "Yes it does!"
End Sub
[Wow! does thi$ really works? I'm a 1337 h4x0rz!]
```

Edit;
Extra-Free-Bonus: A specialcharacter recognition function:

```
Public Function isSpecialCharacter(byVal myChar)
    isSpecialCharacter = (myChar="""")
End Function
```

Comment: Shouldn't your test be  isSpecialCharacter = (myChar = "")?

Comment: Sir, you just invented the isEmptyString function! In the special character case we want to test for a double quote (") and that is escaped by putting another pair of bunny ears in front of it ("") But we still have to define it as string and have to wrap it with double quotes ("""") So, the code will be: isSpecialCharacter = (myChar = "{1. start of string}"{2. escape character}"{3. literal double quote}"{4. end of string})